# If m,n,p,q are non negative integers, then how to prove the following?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, integers

$$\sum_{m=0}^q(n-m)\frac{(p+m)!}{m!}=\frac{(p+q+1)!}{q!}\left(\frac{n}{p+1}-\frac{q}{p+2}\right)$$

I thought of solving it by induction but am unable to fathom which variable should I apply induction principle upon. I thought of applying on q, but I am stuck. Please help.

Comment: If we take $q=1$ then the left hand is $n\times p! + (n-1)\times (p+1)!$ and the right hand is $n\times p! \times (p+2)  - (p+1)!$, not equal in general.  Or have I missed something?

Comment: Let me check, wait a min. please

Comment: My mistake, never mind.  Those two expressions actually are equal, though they certainly don't look it.

Comment: Yes, now you are correct, I almost got confused, those are same when simplified!

Comment: Please would uou help me with an answer?

Comment: Check out what I posted.  Proof is by induction on $q$.  The algebra is simple, but messy and error prone so I recommend checking it carefully.  It should work out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54371/discussion-between-amitayas-banerjee-and-lulu).

Comment: Sorry, I have to run out.  Does the argument look solid? Granted it doesn't convey much insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll proceed by induction on $q$.  The statement can be verified for $q=1$ (though as the comments show, it takes a little effort).  Suppose it is known up to $q-1$, let's address it for $q$.

The left hand is, by induction, $$\frac {(p+q)!}{(q-1)!}\times \left(\frac n{p+1}-\frac {q-1}{p+2}\right)+(n-q)\frac {(p+q)!}{q!}$$

Grouping the terms involving $n$ we get $$n\times \frac {(p+q+1)!}{q!(p+1)}$$

Grouping the terms without $n$ we get $$-\frac {(p+q+1)!}{(q-1)!}\times \frac 1{p+2}$$

Adding these together quickly reduces to the right hand.

Comment: Got it, but is it impossible to assume it true for q and prove for q+1?

Comment: That't the same.  just replace $q$ with $q+1$ everywhere in my argument.  Good way to check that I didn't mess the algebra up anywhere.

Comment: how did you get this equal to RHS

Comment: wait i got it thnx fr the answer :)

Comment: @AYUSHROCKS123  Phew.  Saves me having to recollect the calculation.

Comment: lmfao :) :) :) :)